# How to read or open a qrel format file?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

I was working with TREC qrel file and I would like to have a look at the file. I was wondering how to read a qrel file? or how can I open the file? what is the format> what library should I use?

Comment: This question does not necessarily fall under the NLP tag. It would be wise to change the tag to something that relates to information retrieval / IR. I have posted a possible solution below. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have updated my solution with the right way of doing it if you are interesting in reading qrels as a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you reformat the file into a `.txt` file you would see that the file would have multiple columns, of which one column would be the relevant judgment.

If you are used to working with CSV files and `Python Pandas Dataframes` you can opt to follow these steps:

1. Rename the qrel file with a `.txt` extension. (Just so that you can read it on a notepad or something)
2. Read the file as a usual `.txt` line by line and push it into a CSV file.

Of the top of my head, I have written an easy snippet in `Python` which you could try:

```
import pandas as pd
rel_query = []
with open('/content/renamed_qrel.qrel.txt', 'r') as fp:
    Lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in Lines:
      # The line below may need to be changed based on the type of data in the qrel file
      rel_query.append(line.split())
qrel_df = pd.DataFrame(rel_query)
```

**NOTE:** Although this may/may not be the right way to do it, this surely can help you get started.

I think the right way of doing this would be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('abcd.txt',
                        sep="\s+", # Or whichever seperator
                        names=["A", "B", "C", "D"]) # For header names
```